# Thread.Sleep() and constructor modification?

Tags: c#, thread-sleep

I'm trying to get the constructor of an object to initialize a field to something, pause for 30 seconds, and then set it to something else afterwards.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Practice
{
    public enum TransactionStatus { Pending, Complete }

    public class Transaction
    {
        private TransactionStatus status;

        public Transaction()
        {
            this.status = TransactionStatus.Pending;
            //(I'm trying to set this to TransactionStatus.Complete after 30 seconds. What do I do afterwards?)
        }

        // Here is the method to do it... Am I right to think that.status this must be reset this.status in the constructor?
        public TransactionStatus SetStatus()
        {
            // sleep for 30 seconds and then proceed.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            return TransactionStatus.Complete;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why? I'm almost positive you are doing something really wrong here.

Comment: I'm displaying this as a ToString where it says "Pending..." for 30 seconds, and then "Complete" afterwards.

Comment: Again, I ask *why* are you doing that? What is the purpose for waiting 30 seconds?

Comment: It's a sort of simulation for when a deposit transaction... Our instructor made us pretend that it took 30 seconds to process a transaction, and he wanted us to display it to the user.

Comment: This sounds all wrong. What's you actual goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative cheating method since you said you're using toString();

```
private DateTime called;

public TranlationStatus()
{
    this.called = DateTime.Now; 
}

public ToString()
{
    if (this.called - DateTime.Now < new TimeSpan(0,0,20))
    {
        return TransationStatus.Pending.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return TransactionStatus.Complete.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 no sleeping and no munching around with threads, btw: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)` might be better as it's easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't put it in the constructor to be honest. I'd do it in the main code:

```
TransactionStatus status = new TransactionStatus();

Thread.Sleep(3000);

status.SetStatus();
```

Of course that will block the entire program. If you don't want that, you'll have to write your own function and call it as a separate thread. Again in the main code.

That said I really can;t understand why you want to do something like this.

Comment: Makes no difference whether it happens inside or outside the constructor.

Comment: I guess not. I just don't like putting Thread sleeping statuses into constructors. Its a huge negative for reusability and someone else debugging the code.

Comment: Well, I never use sleep anywhere ever in real code. But I guess this is homework so normal rules don't apply.

Comment: Is it me, or does programming homework just plain suck these days? hehe

Comment: Any suggestions on where I can learn better?

Comment: Learn better what? Programming practices? Those either come with formal teaching or experience.